# debian rsync much slower from cron than from command line

Tags: debian, cron, rsync

If I run this command from cron

```
rsync -aAXv / --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/var/lib/plexmediaserver/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} /mnt/4TB/weatherbackup*
```

it runs for many hours and sometimes over a day.

If I manually run exactly the same command from the shell it completes in less than a minute.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that your system's cron is using a shell that supports brace expansion? if not, then likely your `--exclude` is not excluding what you expect it to

Comment: Yes I think that's it.  I revised the cron task removing the braces section and it ran normally.  Thanks!